# PHP CURL connection timed out problem in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I was trying to get the data from the API using php curl in WordPress but I faced the connection timed out problem. I shared the code.

```
<?php
 $curl = curl_init();
 $header = [];
 $header[0] = "Content-Type: application/json";
 $curl_url = "server url";
 curl_setopt_array($curl, [
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
   CURLOPT_URL => $curl_url,
 ]);

 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 echo curl_error($curl);
 $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($curl);
 if ($http_status != 200) {
    echo $http_status;
 } else {
    $apps = json_decode($result);
 }
```

?>

Also, I tried to do that with the related article in StackOverflow or the others but I got the same problem.

```
Failed connect to "server"; Connection timed out
```

how can I solve this problem? do you have any good idea?

Comment: You should put valid url for variable  `$curl_url`

Comment: @JatinKaklotar that's the valid url